# XML XSLT help parent child with auto gen PK and FK

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML structure with an organization hierarchy but with no relationship or 'keys' defined

Here is my xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<webreports>
<entity>
    <entity_name>Device Liquid Flow Daily</entity_name>
    <db_name>DeviceLiquidFlowDaily</db_name>
    <category>Scada</category>
    <datasource_id>2</datasource_id>
    <object_type>table</object_type>
    <schema>rpt</schema>
    <key>
      <col_name>DeviceKey</col_name>
    </key>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>CalendarKey</col_name>
      <col_type>int</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>ClientCode</col_name>
      <col_type>string</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>ContractHour</col_name>
      <col_type>int</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>DeviceId</col_name>
      <col_type>int</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>DeviceKey</col_name>
      <col_type>int</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>FlowPeriodDateUTC</col_name>
      <col_type>datetime</col_type>
      <visible>false</visible>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>FlowPeriodEndingUTC</col_name>
      <col_type>datetime</col_type>
      <visible>false</visible>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>FlowPeriodStartingUTC</col_name>
      <col_type>datetime</col_type>
      <visible>false</visible>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>OilVolume</col_name>
      <col_type>float</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>OilVolumeUOM</col_name>
      <col_type>string</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>RecordCreationDateUTC</col_name>
      <col_type>datetime</col_type>
      <visible>false</visible>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>SystemCreationDateUTC</col_name>
      <col_type>datetime</col_type>
      <visible>false</visible>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>WaterVolume</col_name>
      <col_type>float</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>WaterVolumeUOM</col_name>
      <col_type>string</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_source>ExagoFormula</col_source>
      <col_name>FlowPeriodDate</col_name>
      <col_type>datetime</col_type>
      <col_alias>FlowPeriodDate</col_alias>
      <filterable>None</filterable>
      <col_value>UTCConvertToLocal({DeviceLiquidFlowDaily.FlowPeriodDateUTC})</col_value>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_source>ExagoFormula</col_source>
      <col_name>FlowPeriodEnding</col_name>
      <col_type>datetime</col_type>
      <col_alias>FlowPeriodEnding</col_alias>
      <filterable>None</filterable>
      <col_value>UTCConvertToLocal({DeviceLiquidFlowDaily.FlowPeriodEndingUTC})</col_value>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_source>ExagoFormula</col_source>
      <col_name>FlowPeriodStarting</col_name>
      <col_type>datetime</col_type>
      <col_alias>FlowPeriodStarting</col_alias>
      <filterable>None</filterable>
      <col_value>UTCConvertToLocal({DeviceLiquidFlowDaily.FlowPeriodStartingUTC})</col_value>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_source>ExagoFormula</col_source>
      <col_name>RecordCreationDate</col_name>
      <col_type>datetime</col_type>
      <col_alias>RecordCreationDate</col_alias>
      <filterable>None</filterable>
      <col_value>UTCConvertToLocal({DeviceLiquidFlowDaily.RecordCreationDateUTC})</col_value>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_source>ExagoFormula</col_source>
      <col_name>SystemCreationDate</col_name>
      <col_type>datetime</col_type>
      <col_alias>SystemCreationDate</col_alias>
      <filterable>None</filterable>
      <col_value>UTCConvertToLocal({DeviceLiquidFlowDaily.SystemCreationDateUTC})</col_value>
    </column_metadata>
  </entity>
  <entity>
    <entity_name>Tank Level</entity_name>
    <db_name>TankLevel</db_name>
    <category>Scada</category>
    <datasource_id>2</datasource_id>
    <object_type>table</object_type>
    <schema>rpt</schema>
    <key>
      <col_name>DeviceKey</col_name>
    </key>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>CalendarKey</col_name>
      <col_type>int</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>ClientCode</col_name>
      <col_type>string</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>DeviceId</col_name>
      <col_type>int</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>DeviceKey</col_name>
      <col_type>int</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>FluidLevelDateTimeUTC</col_name>
      <col_type>date</col_type>
      <visible>false</visible>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>RecordCreationDateUTC</col_name>
      <col_type>date</col_type>
      <visible>false</visible>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>SourceModifiedDate</col_name>
      <col_type>date</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>TankId</col_name>
      <col_type>int</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>TankKey</col_name>
      <col_type>int</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>TankLevel1</col_name>
      <col_type>float</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>TankLevel2</col_name>
      <col_type>float</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>TankLevel3</col_name>
      <col_type>float</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_name>Temperature</col_name>
      <col_type>float</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_source>ExagoFormula</col_source>
      <col_name>FluidLevelDateTime</col_name>
      <col_type>datetime</col_type>
      <col_alias>FluidLevelDateTime</col_alias>
      <filterable>None</filterable>
      <col_value>UTCConvertToLocal({TankLevel.FluidLevelDateTimeUTC})</col_value>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_source>ExagoFormula</col_source>
      <col_name>RecordCreationDate</col_name>
      <col_type>datetime</col_type>
      <col_alias>RecordCreationDate</col_alias>
      <filterable>None</filterable>
      <col_value>UTCConvertToLocal({TankLevel.RecordCreationDateUTC})</col_value>
    </column_metadata>
  </entity>
  </webreports>
```

I need a XSLT that will produce the following output

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<webreports>
<entity>
    <entity_name>Device Liquid Flow Daily</entity_name>
    <db_name>DeviceLiquidFlowDaily</db_name>
    <category>Scada</category>
    <datasource_id>2</datasource_id>
    <object_type>table</object_type>
    <schema>rpt</schema>
    <key>
      <col_name_entityKEY>Device Liquid Flow Daily</col_name_entityKEY>
      <col_name>DeviceKey</col_name>
    </key>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_metadata_entityKEY>Device Liquid Flow Daily</col_metadata_entityKEY>
      <col_name>CalendarKey</col_name>
      <col_type>int</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_metadata_entityKEY>Device Liquid Flow Daily</col_metadata_entityKEY>
      <col_name>ClientCode</col_name>
      <col_type>string</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_metadata_entityKEY>Device Liquid Flow Daily</col_metadata_entityKEY>
      <col_name>ContractHour</col_name>
      <col_type>int</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    ...
  </entity>
  <entity>
    <entity_name>Tank Level</entity_name>
    <db_name>TankLevel</db_name>
    <category>Scada</category>
    <datasource_id>2</datasource_id>
    <object_type>table</object_type>
    <schema>rpt</schema>
    <key>
      <col_name_entityKEY>Tank Level</col_name_entityKEY>
      <col_name>DeviceKey</col_name>
    </key>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_metadata_entityKEY>Tank Level</col_metadata_entityKEY>
      <col_name>CalendarKey</col_name>
      <col_type>int</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_metadata_entityKEY>Tank Level</col_metadata_entityKEY>
      <col_name>ClientCode</col_name>
      <col_type>string</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    </column_metadata>
    <column_metadata>
      <col_metadata_entityKEY>Tank Level</col_metadata_entityKEY>
      <col_name>DeviceId</col_name>
      <col_type>int</col_type>
      <filterable>All</filterable>
    ...
 
  </webreports>
```

so basically I need to associate each child key and child column_metadata element with the parent - entity

any and all help is appreciated!

I have tried this....

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
 
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 
 <!-- Identity transformation: copy all nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template match="column_metadata">
        <column_metadata>
            <C_NOT><xsl:value-of select="@entity"/></C_NOT>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </column_metadata>
    </xsl:template>
 
 <!-- overrides identity template if node is datasource (this element should be ignored) -->
    <xsl:template match="datasource"/>
 <!-- overrides identity template if node is parameter (this element should be ignored) -->
    <xsl:template match="parameter"/>
 <!-- overrides identity template if node is role (this element should be ignored) -->
    <xsl:template match="role"/>
 <!-- overrides identity template if node is function (this element should be ignored) -->
    <xsl:template match="function"/>
 <!-- overrides identity template if node is serverevent (this element should be ignored) -->
    <xsl:template match="serverevent"/>
 <!-- overrides identity template if node is serverevent (this element should be ignored) -->
    <xsl:template match="general"/>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would these two templates do it...

```
<xsl:template match="column_metadata">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <col_metadata_entityKEY>
      <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::entity/entity_name" />
    </col_metadata_entityKEY>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="key">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <col_name_entityKEY>
      <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::entity/entity_name" />
    </col_name_entityKEY>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or maybe you can combine them into one...

```
<xsl:template match="key|column_metadata">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:element name="{if (local-name() = 'key') then 'col_name' else 'col_metadata'}_entityKEY">
      <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::entity/entity_name" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: YES! thank you! I think I tried about 20 different combinations - thanks for ending my misery :)